# Combining elements of list

Tags: python

**Question**: 
Given a set of numbers `S_a={n1,n2,n3,...,na}` produce the following combination of numbers of the type:

```
{Sk,Sp}, where k=1...a, p=k+1,..,a
```

One can easily construct this solution as a loop:

```
N = len(S)
for i in range(0, N):
    for j in range(i+1, N):
                 print("%d,%d" %(i,j))
```

But I am looking for a vectorized solution.

---

Another variation of this is to consider a list of objects:

```
class A:
    def function(self, a):
        pass
L = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 ]

#where a1,a2,an are of class A.
```

how to write the a vectorized version of this loop:

```
N = len(L)-1
for i in range(0, N):
    for j in range(i+1, N):
        L[i].function(L[j])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "vectorized"? Usually, in Python numerical programming, by "vectorized" people mean "the inner loop happens inside `numpy` C code". But you don't have any `numpy` anywhere, so I suspect you may mean something different here.

Comment: @abarnert was that downvote yours? Or someone confused with the mathematical phrasing of the question?

Comment: I didn't vote on the question either way. Especially for newer users, unless the OP actively refuses to provide enough information to make it a useful question, I won't usually downvote.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) instead:

```
L = list(itertools.combinations(S, 2))
```

The documentation details the implementation if you want to pick it it apart.

It's easy enough to apply this to the list of objects you have:

```
for i, j in itertools.combinations(L, 2):
    i.function(j)
```

Comment: +1 to @Hoopdady, but also an actual +1 to the answer instead of just saying it. :)

Comment: @abarnert Was waiting to see if it actually was the answer... since I don't know what's being asked. :-)

Comment: I think function call is still missing: `map(lambda ai, aj: ai.function(aj), L)`

Comment: @ChrisWesseling: Not sure I'd use a `map()` call for that. I'd rather make it an explicit loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: me too, but map fits nicely in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If by "vectorized" you mean "the inner loop happens in `numpy` C code":

[`scipy.misc.comb`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/misc.html#scipy.misc.comb) is the simplest way to generate combinations.

For the more general case of operating on `L[i], L[j]` for all `i != j`, or `i < j`, or whatever other case you're considering, there are a few ways to do it—you can explicitly use `broadcast`, or you can create a "column-vector" and a "row-vector" out of L and just perform the operation, or you can create a 2D array of shifted copies of L and apply the operation against that, or… it really depends on what you're doing.